# Como autoexecutar um script durante a inialização do Linux?

Tags: linux, boot

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que deve ser executado automaticamente logo após
a inicialização do Linux.

Para ser mais específico estou desenvolvendo para Debian e para rodar na Beaglebone Black.
Eu preciso executar alguns comandos shell e então executar o programa.

Atualmente eu só consigo executar o programa, mas eu preciso executar um script antes.
Para isso, eu estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
cd /lib/systemd/system/
sudo nano autorun.service
```

Preencho com:

```
[Unit]
Description=Auto start software.

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/App/
ExecStart=/home/debian/Texas/App
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

E por fim:

```
systemctl enable rtu.service
```

---

Resumindo, como faço para auto executar um script e então o programa logo após o boot no Linux?

Comment: O arquivo tem que ser criado todas as vezes que você dá boot?

Comment: @VictorHugo Verifiquei aqui e aparentemente não precisa, o programa é iniciado desde que eu já o tenha ativado. Nesse caso, o script fica resumido só as outros comandos que vou acrescentar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode colocar o seu script no `/etc/rc.local`. O `rc.local` é um script executado no boot do Linux para automatizar o início dos serviços desejados pelo usuário.

Não entendi muito bem se é necessário criar o arquivo todas as vezes que é dado o boot, então acrescentei também a criação do arquivo na solução. Caso não precise criar o arquivo sempre, é só remover as linhas.

```bash
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will “exit 0″ on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing

# criando o arquivo autorun.service
echo "[Unit]
Description=Auto start software.

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/App/
ExecStart=/home/debian/Texas/App
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target" > /lib/systemd/system/autorun.service

# executa o comando
systemctl enable rtu.service

exit 0;
```

O `echo` escreve na saída padrão que é redirecionado para o arquivo `autorun.service` usando `>`.